# Confused about type declaration in Java after seeing enum

Tags: java, enums

As a beginner in Java I was introduced to enums and that just got me really confused with type declaration. I would like to share what I know, so that one of you might find a problem in the way I think.

I have learned that there are two datatypes, primitive datatypes and object datatypes. When declaring a variable, you first write the **datatype** and then the **identifier** of the variable.

When I declared a datatype int variable, I have the following idea in my head:

```
int a = 1; int as datatype references to the primitive integer datatype.
```

When I declared a datatype Integer variable, I have the following idea in my head:

```
Integer b =  1;  Integer as datatype references to the object datatype (that in this case is an instance of the class integer)
```

When I declare an enumerator variable, I have the following idea in my head:

```
enum C {EXAMPLE1, EXAMPLE2}; No clue what enum references to.. Is it an object datatype and an instance of class enum? If so, where is the capital letter E in enum.
```

So here the problem starts. I have learned that enum is not a primitive datatype, so the only posibility is that it is an object. But I have also learned that declaring an object of a class as datatype means that the identifier should start with a capital letter like Integer, Boolean etc. I can however declare an enum without a capital letter. Does this mean it is not an object? Or is an enumerator just a keyword like class and not a variable datatype like I assumed it to be.

If enum is not a variable datatype but rather a keyword like class then I wonder if the following mindset is correct:

```
enum Test {EXAMPLE1, EXAMPLE2}
Test e = Test.EXAMPLE; Does Test reference to the object datatype? (That 
in this case is an instance of the enumerator Test)
```

If Test is an instance of the enumerator **Test**, how is this possible? I only thought it was possible to create objects from classes but I have also read something about constructors in enumerators.

I have been looking for answers on this question for a couple of hours now with no success. I hope I haven't messed up your head by now. But I truely hope that there is someone that can make some sense of this and actually help me out.

Comment: Got to ask: what does this have to do with C#?

Comment: By the way the capitalization is just a convention, it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: I am not very common with C# but I have heard often that C# and Java are related in syntax. One that understands C# would probably understand my question as well and help me out.

Comment: For the Java/C# thing, unfortunately enums is one of the few areas where they are very different.

Comment: In Java enums are objects with a backing integer known as the ordinal. In C# an enum is basically a named int (it can actually be any primitive data type). C# enums are more analogous to that of C/C++, except that their names are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can however declare an enum without a capital letter. Does this mean it is not an object?

No.

> Or is an enumerator just a keyword like class and not a variable datatype like I assumed it to be.

`enum`, like `class`, is a keyword -- see [JLS section 8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9).

> An enum declaration specifies a new enum type, a special kind of class type.

enum constants are instances of the enum type, which in turn extends the `Enum` superclass.

```
enum Test {EXAMPLE1, EXAMPLE2}
```

So here `Test` defines an enum type.  EXAMPLE1 and EXAMPLE2 are enum constants, which are instances of the Test enum type.  No other instances can be created at runtime, but you can create other references to those instances.

```
Test e = Test.EXAMPLE
```

So here, the local variable e points to the enum constant; `e` and `Test.EXAMPLE` have the same address in memory, so to speak.

`Test.class` is a construction that makes sense - it gives you access to the class instance defined by the enum declaration.  `Test.EXAMPLE.class` doesn't make sense, nor does `e.class`, because those are *instances*.  `Test.EXAMPLE.getClass()` and `e.getClass()`

It's very much like `java.lang.Boolean`

```
Boolean b = Boolean.TRUE
```

but not exactly

```
Boolean b = new Boolean(true); // OK
Test    t = new Test(); // NOT ALLOWED
```

Comment: Thank you so much ;) After seeing how the compiler handles the enum's and you mentioning that the constants are instances it all made sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You can think of an `enum` as a special java type for declaring a "group of constants". Simple example:

```
enum Language {
    PORTUGUESE,
    ENGLISH
}
```

Usage:

```
Language yourLanguage = Language.ENGLISH;

if (language == Language.ENGLISH) {
    System.out.println("Hi!");
}
```

To this extent, you can think of `Language` as the enum type, and `PORTUGUESE` and `ENGLISH` as constants from this type. When you eventually start to explore enum's capabilities beyond just defining these constants by names, it becomes clearer that these constants are indeed objects, with fields and methods. Example:

```
enum Language {
    PORTUGUESE("Olá!"), // Call to constructor initializing PORTUGUESE instance
    ENGLISH("Hi!");   // Call to constructor initializing ENGLISH instance

    private final String greeting; // Instance field

    // Constructor!
    Language(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    public void greet() {
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Language yourLang = Language.ENGLISH;
yourLang.greet();
```

Comment: @EmreGülten np! Do you mind picking an answer and marking as accepted?